# How to get customer address as they sign up

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there any way to add the address form to the registration form or any free addon to add an extra field to the registration form so that I can get the customer location as they sign up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

defiant,

Create local.xml file at  in `app/design/your package/your template/layout/` folder and add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account_create>
        <reference name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setData"><key>show_address_fields</key><value>1</value></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>
</layout>
```

Comment: Yep, it's already built in, just has to be enabled.

Comment: I added this to app/design/frontend/default/dresscode/layout/local.xml, but nevertheless the address field is not being shown while registering!

Comment: have you create local.xml for first times...??

Comment: But the local.xml is already there!

Comment: remove <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0"> and </layout>

Comment: regsiter.phtml have  if($this->getShowAddressFields()) code?

Comment: It worked. I added the thing in the wrong place in local.xml. I just moved it to the beginning right after<layout> and it worked. Thanks man!